# How to store a 250mb database in an Offline Web App

Tags: javascript, iphone, database, web-applications, local-storage

Ok, maybe i'm not seeing the whole picture or something, but i kinda need a brainstorm.

So the purpose is to make a webapp (HTML5, CSS, Javascript) that has to search on a 250mb database without any internet connection, so.. yes the database has to be on the client side.

The hard part here is, this App has to work on an iPod or iPhone without internet connection. (An initial connection to download the App is ok), LocalStorage has a 5mb limit, couchDB would be great since they have an webapp easily accessed by Javascript (privacy concerns don't matter at this point), so i'm pretty much out of ideas....

Does anyone see an alternative, or solution for the purpose?

Comment: Hmm. That may be a case for a native app, I know of no methods to store those amounts  of data locally in a web app

Comment: How did you get to the point where you concluded you need to drag around a 250MB file with your application?  What's the bigger picture?

Comment: Although the main target is the iPhone, to be able to access through androids is quite welcome, that's the main reason for being a web app instead of a native app.

Comment: @Pointy because all the data that i need to store takes 250mb on a MySQL database, and that would be perfectly ok, if i had internet connection.

Comment: Keep the data in-memory, and then hope the OS never shuts your app down, which it would only do in the event that it needed to reclaim, um, memory, not that your 250 MB would be a candidate or anything.

Comment: @Couto: there are cross-platform alternatives to web apps that cover both iPhone and Android.

Comment: 250mb is just not right, find a way tooptimize that, even if you were allowed to store that 250mb on a user's device, it just seems careless and not economic to do such. find a way around storing what a user needs at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the tools best fitting for the job... and this seems to be a client-app-job. Here is a small tutorial how to use a database (sqlite) on the iPhone and you should be able to use any other embeddable database availalable for the iPhone/iPad, too.

[Sqlite on the iPhone Tutorial](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)

If you are really forced to use HTML5 and the web widget stuff you mentioned above you wil have the option to embed a browser window into a native app and react for url changes or post/get messages.

Comment: I've never used SQLite before, so out of inexperience and lazyness i'm going to ask, is SQLite like MySQL or can it be downloaded to the client side?

Comment: SQLite is very simple to use and has several benefits for usage in environments with limited capabilities, for example it is serverless and needs no complex configuration to run (very good for out-of-the-box deployment). Simply, it is just a library for accessing a database file format with SQL statements and ACID. SQLite is widely used and proven (for example Mozilla is using it for its cache as far as I know). There are existing many language bindings (e.g. for C#, C/C++, PHP, Java, ...) and so SQLite can be used in the language of your choice. See http://www.sqlite.org/ for more infos.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to store a 250MB database in 5MB of storage.

Possible work-arounds:

1. If you know about your data, you can write a specialized compression algorithm.
2. Store only a subset of the data offline which you think that user will use.  If they need other data, then they will need to connect.
3. Don't include images, sounds, videos, etc. in the offline data, but include all the text.  5MB will hold a lot of text, but not very many pictures and graphics.